# Modelling Business Rules Data

Tags: java, database-design, data-modeling, modeling

I got a design question out here. I am trying to model a rules table.

My sample rules would like:
    Given a data row I would go through all the rules that are configured, and if any column name matches value rule would be hit.

e.g

[image]

now in incoming data row if the column **country** has **US** as value i would hit rule 1003.

Designing my rules table this way helps me to add any column(that's part of data row) to rules easily. My user's can view the rule and manage it themselves.

Now the problem here is with priority column.  Whenever new rule needs to be added which has priority in between I need to update priority of all the rows after that.
For instance in above example I need to add something at priority 3:
below I need to update two more rule.
[image]

As table becomes big it wont be manageable to keep updating all the rows. This makes me feel there must be a better solution for this.

I need priority column as in need to define order in which rules need to be selected.

Can someone please advise what would be better rule model for this use case?

**PS I cant use drools or any rule engine because of my execution environment.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions that would reduce the problem of having more updates that necessary

Do the values in the priority column have to be consecutive? If not, set up the initial set of rule with values with plenty of gaps (e.g. 100, 200, 300...) this won't affect the ordering and any new rule can be added in the spaces.

Any sub set of rules that are exclusive could share the same priority value e.g. Only one of the 'country' rules will ever match so there is no need to evaluate them in turn (Of course you should consider performance here, if 90% of country rules will match 'US' then it still makes sense to evaluate this one first).

There are some other limitations with the current design that go beyond the updates problem. e.g. If in the future you wanted to treat a UK-equity differently from a US-equity how would you set up those rules?